# Assigning new values from another column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to make a new column in R that contain values from another column but I need to reassign them. This is an example:
The data is look like this:

```
ID column1  column2 
1  C*0421   C*0232
2  C*0531   C*0332
3  C*0502   C*0544
4  C*0432   C*0132
5  C*0632   C*0703
```

So what I want is to create a new column that should assign anything starts with :

```
C*04 should be C1
C*05 should be C2
C*07 should be C1
C*02 should be C2 
NA   should be NA
```

and the final results should look like this:

```
ID column1  column2   results_from_column1  results_from_column2     Combining_the_results
1  C*0421   C*0232     C1                        C2                       C1/C2
2  C*0531   C*0332     C2                        C1                       C2/C1
3  C*0502   C*0544     C2                        C2                       C2/C2  
4  C*0432   C*0132     C1                        C1                       C1/C1
5  C*0632   C*0703     C2                        C1                       C2/C1
```

I tried to use this code but it gave me wrong assigning for some of the values and i did not know why

```
df2<- 
  df1%>% 
  mutate(
    C.groups = case_when(
      str_detect(column1, "C*01")~ "C1",
      str_detect(column2, "C*03") ~ "C1", 
        is.na(HLA.C) ~ "NA",
         TRUE ~ "C2"
    )
  )
```

Please, can you help me?

Comment: Note: `HLA.C` is not part of your sample dataframe.  In your code you assign `C*03` to be "C1"` but in your declaration tabel 'should be'  `C*03`  is not mentioned.

Comment: Would you please check your conditions? I would like to know I should set them based on your code or on what you defined in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(!ID, ~ case_when(
    grepl("C*04", .) ~ "C1",
    grepl("C*05", .) ~ "C2",
    grepl("C*07", .) ~ "C2",
    grepl("C*02", .) ~ "C2",
    NA ~ NA_character_,
    TRUE ~ "C2"), .names = "results_from_{.col}")) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Combining_the_results = paste(results_from_column1, results_from_column2, 
                                        sep = "/"))

# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Rowwise: 
     ID column1 column2 results_from_column1 results_from_column2 Combining_the_results
  <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>                <chr>                <chr>                
1     1 C*0421  C*0232  C1                   C2                   C1/C2                
2     2 C*0531  C*0332  C2                   C2                   C2/C2                
3     3 C*0502  C*0544  C2                   C2                   C2/C2                
4     4 C*0432  C*0132  C1                   C2                   C1/C2                
5     5 C*0632  C*0703  C2                   C2                   C2/C2
```

Comment: @MarwahAl-kaabi It means every other conditions will result to `C2` as I specified 4 conditions plus 1 for `NA` values. I took that from your code. The second vector doesn't correspond with your desired output but there is nothing wrong with it apparently as I checked. Is there any condition except for what I defined to be taken into account?

Comment: yes, I have so many conditions but I did not want to complicate the example, but your codes worked perfectly I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad it helped. You can modify conditions yourself but be aware that you write them from the most specific to the most general. If only two conditions are going to be `C1` you can write them first the way TarJae and Anil specified and define all `C2`s with `TRUE` expression.

Answer (score 3):

The asterisk (`*`) in the string pattern is treated as a wild card character in `str_detect` (or `grepl` or other functions that uses regular expressions, too).  You need to add two backslashes (`\\`) to before the asterisk to escape the special behaviour (i.e., replace `*` with `\\*` in the string).

```r
library(tidyverse)

# example data (I added one new row to illustrate the code that you have)
df1 <- data.frame(
    index = 1:6, 
    column1 = c("C*0421", "C*0531", "C*0502", "C*0432", "C*0332", "C*0123"), 
    column2 = c("C*0232", "C*0332", "C*0544", "C*0132", "C*0703", "C*0987")) 


df1%>% # based on the code you're using
    mutate(
        C.groups = case_when(
            str_detect(column1, "C\\*01") ~ "C1",
            str_detect(column2, "C\\*03") ~ "C1"
        )
    )

#  index column1 column2 C.groups
#1     1  C*0421  C*0232     <NA>
#2     2  C*0531  C*0332       C1
#3     3  C*0502  C*0544     <NA>
#4     4  C*0432  C*0132     <NA>
#5     5  C*0332  C*0703     <NA>
#6     6  C*0123  C*0987       C1
```

See here for details about regular expressions: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html

If I'm following your conditions, as described in the OP, and creating the new desired column variables, then it would be like this:

```r
df1%>% 
    mutate(
        results_from_column1 = case_when(
            str_detect(column1, "^C\\*04") ~ "C1", # anything starts with C*04 should be C1
            str_detect(column1, "^C\\*05") ~ "C2", # anything starts with C*05 should be C2
            str_detect(column1, "^C\\*07") ~ "C1", # anything starts with C*07 should be C1
            str_detect(column1, "^C\\*02") ~ "C2"  # anything starts with C*02 should be C2 
        ),
        results_from_column2 = case_when(
            str_detect(column2, "^C\\*04") ~ "C1", # anything starts with C*04 should be C1
            str_detect(column2, "^C\\*05") ~ "C2", # anything starts with C*05 should be C2
            str_detect(column2, "^C\\*07") ~ "C1", # anything starts with C*07 should be C1
            str_detect(column2, "^C\\*02") ~ "C2"  # anything starts with C*02 should be C2 
        ), 
        Combining_the_results = paste0(results_from_column1, "/", results_from_column2)
    )

#  index column1 column2 results_from_column1 results_from_column2 Combining_the_results
#1     1  C*0421  C*0232                   C1                   C2                 C1/C2
#2     2  C*0531  C*0332                   C2                 <NA>                 C2/NA
#3     3  C*0502  C*0544                   C2                   C2                 C2/C2
#4     4  C*0432  C*0132                   C1                 <NA>                 C1/NA
#5     5  C*0332  C*0703                 <NA>                   C1                 NA/C1
```

Note 1 – Undefined cases for `case_when` become NA's in the new column; thus, defining "NA should be NA" would be unnecessary when using `case_when`. 
Note 2 – There are some NA's because they were not defined in your conditions in the original post. (Hence, the output based on your assignment conditions is different from your expected final results.) 
Note 3 – The caret (`^`) at the beginning of the string pattern (e.g., `"^C\\*04"`) is a special/regex character that [anchors](https://towardsdatascience.com/anchors-away-more-regex-concepts-in-r-f00fe7f07d52) the matched string pattern to the beginning of the text. Although it's unnecessary with this example data here, I added it to be elaborate and meet the condition, "anything starts with ..."

Comment: using the ``` \\```  has solved the problem perfectly;)

Answer (score 3):

We could `mutate` `across` over columns `column1` to `column2`
Use `case_when` for our condition as you mentioned in your question
and `mutate` the `Combining_the_results` column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    mutate(across(starts_with("column"), ~case_when(
        str_detect(., "C*01|C*03|C*04|C*07") ~ "C1",
        str_detect(., "C*02|C*05") ~ "C2",
        is.na(.) ~ NA_character_,
        TRUE ~ "C2"), .names = "results_from_{.col}")) %>% 
    mutate(Combining_the_results = paste(results_from_column1, results_from_column2, sep="/"))
```

output:

```
 ID column1 column2 results_from_column1 results_from_column2 Combining_the_results
1  1  C*0421  C*0232                   C1                   C2                 C1/C2
2  2  C*0531  C*0332                   C2                   C1                 C2/C1
3  3  C*0502  C*0544                   C2                   C2                 C2/C2
4  4  C*0432  C*0132                   C1                   C1                 C1/C1
5  5  C*0632  C*0703                   C2                   C1                 C2/C1
```

Comment: How come you get a different result? I checked the conditions and it appeared correct as `C*05` and `C*02` are resulting in `C2` and all the others also result to `C2`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The conditions vary see my comment to OP.

Comment: Yes you are right. I noticed my second result all ended up with `C2` but the conditions also seemed to be correct.

Comment: Anyway. By the way I copied your  `.names = "results_from_{.col}"))`. I was wondering why mine didn't work and my failure was this: `), .names = "results_from_{.col}")`. I put it one parenthesis too late. As I mentioned earlier you are my inspiration! ;-)

Comment: I'm going to sue you for that lol. @Anil Goyal was my inspiration he uses `gsub` and `sub` in `.names` argument to create more custom names. I saw it also when Ms. Camille used it once.

Comment: @AnilGoyal. You are my teacher and also inspiration for me. I learned a lot of things from your answers and I will keep on learning. :-)

Comment: @TarJae we all are here for learning only.  :)  Good luck dear

Comment: @ TarJae Does starts with here can go through many columns in my data?

Comment: It depends on the names of your other columns. If they start with  "column" then yes. Otherwise it is not a big issue to define all the columns. On strategy could be consider all but ID column like Anoushiravan did in his code `!ID`.

Answer (score 3):

```r
df <- read.table(header = T, text = 'ID column1  column2 
1  C*0421   C*0232
2  C*0531   C*0332
3  C*0502   C*0544
4  C*0432   C*0132
5  C*0632   C*0703')

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('column'), ~ c('C2', 'C1')[1 +(substr(., 3, 4) %in% c('04', '07'))],
                .names = 'results_from_{.col}')) %>%
  mutate(combining_the_results = pmap(select(cur_data(), starts_with('results')), ~ paste(c(...), collapse = '/')))

  ID column1 column2 results_from_column1 results_from_column2 combining_the_results
1  1  C*0421  C*0232                   C1                   C2                 C1/C2
2  2  C*0531  C*0332                   C2                   C2                 C2/C2
3  3  C*0502  C*0544                   C2                   C2                 C2/C2
4  4  C*0432  C*0132                   C1                   C2                 C1/C2
5  5  C*0632  C*0703                   C2                   C1                 C2/C1
```

---

If you want to use `C1` for `"C*01|C*03|C*04|C*07"` as shown in example, please modify the code as

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('column'), ~ c('C2', 'C1')[1 +(substr(., 3, 4) %in% c('04', '07', '01', '03'))],
                .names = 'results_from_{.col}')) %>%
  mutate(combining_the_results = pmap(select(cur_data(), starts_with('results')), ~ paste(c(...), collapse = '/')))

  ID column1 column2 results_from_column1 results_from_column2 combining_the_results
1  1  C*0421  C*0232                   C1                   C2                 C1/C2
2  2  C*0531  C*0332                   C2                   C1                 C2/C1
3  3  C*0502  C*0544                   C2                   C2                 C2/C2
4  4  C*0432  C*0132                   C1                   C1                 C1/C1
5  5  C*0632  C*0703                   C2                   C1                 C2/C1
```

Comment: @AnilGoyl. Perfect. But compare the `combining_the_results` with OP.

Comment: @TarJae, you are using `C1` for `"C*01|C*03|C*04|C*07"` whereas OP hasn't mentioned that.  Nevertheless that's not a big deal.  Let me revise it

Comment: Not at all dear AnilGoyal It was just a friendly reminder as I know that you have perfect answers all the time and helped me a lot.

Comment: @TarJae, O yes I took it as a friendly reminder only.  Thanks for pointing it out.  :)